# rm: no se puede eliminar: Permiso denegado

Tags: javascript, git, git-bash

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas tengo un problema de git es que trato de eliminar un archivo txt con rm y me salta esto ,
rm: no se puede eliminar: Permiso denegado , es de git espero que me ayuden

Comment: si le das un `ls -l` te sale quien es el propietario del archivo y solo el puede borrarlo o el `root` en este caso el usuario que instalo `mingw64`

Comment: A lo mismo te estás confundiendo con [`git rm`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2047477/13419694) si lo que quieres es quitar un archivo del repositorio. Si quieres borrar un archivo cualquiera en tu sistema operativo por consola, puedes usar el símbolo del sistema, la [nueva terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) o si quieres un terminal Linux, usa wsl e instala una distro.